# Understanding the Ruling on being in an isolated place for opposite gender

Tags: fatwa, non-mahram, fatwa-explanation

I came across this [fatwa](https://islamqa.info/en/146441) and I can understand to the point that it is forbidden to be in 'an isolated Place' in which a man and a woman will be together based on the hadiths in the fatwa .

But in what contexts were these hadiths told by the prophet (pbuh) ?
Can you state some situations where else the word 'khalwah' has been used ? (During the time of prophet)

What are other fatwas or interpretations of these hadiths ?(Sunni opinions)

If I take this fatwa too seriously, I cannot enter even shops where there is only a female sitting, same would apply for my sister/mother/wife who would want to shop. Neither can I enter in a taxi which would be driven by a female.
Also, if I am walking on an isolated street and a woman is Approaching, I must suddenly run away to the closest shop that has at least a male. The practicality of such fatwas is really questionable.
My purpose of asking this question is to simply categorize the places I visit.
For me the definition of isolated place is where you intentionally go with the expectation that no one else can know your presence with the woman.(examples: an isolated field visit purposely, locked room etc)
The places that do not fall in this category of isolated places: shops, taxis, streets, common rooms in offices/schools where anyone can enter exit/enter anytime etc.

Comment: Khalwa or Khulwa basically is a term (noun) invented by scholars based on the verb khala خلى yakhlu يخلو the fiqh meaning of Khalwa or khulwa comes from this hadith. Linguistically it comes from leaving alone or being alone.

Comment: There is the actual hadith where men & women entered mosque by the same door and prayed under the same roof. I will look for that hadith and return here with reference or link.

Answer (score 1):

There are orders in Islam about sin to restrict it and there are order about prevention to avoid committing sin.

Your examples above definitely not comes in this prevention if you don't have intention and after all this is order of prevention to avoid sin.

Answer (score 0):

One should avoid being alone with a person of an opposite gender as it’s not allowed

عن ابن عباس رضي الله عنهما أن رسول الله صلى الله عليه وسلم قال: **لا يخلون رجل بامرأة إلا مع ذي محرم**. وقال صلى الله عليه وسلم: **ألا لا يخلون رجل بامرأة إلا كان ثالثهما الشيطان**. رواه أحمد والترمذي عن ابن عمر رضي الله عنهما. وروى الطبراني عن ابن عباس رضي الله عنهما أن النبي صلى الله عليه وسلم قال: **من كان يؤمن بالله واليوم الآخر فلا يخلون بامرأة ليس بينها وبينه محرم**

Public places could be an exception as anyone could walk-in on them and they are not hidden in a private place.